# Derive a class from a derived class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have 3 classes (`City`, `Neighborhood`, and `Block`).

Here is the definition of the `City` class:

```
class City:
    def __init__(self, id_city, name_city):
        self.__id = id_city
        self.__name = name_city
```

Definition of the `Neighborhood`:

```
class Neighborhood(City):
    def __init__(self, id_neighborhood, name_neighborhood, number_block, *city_args, **kwargs):
        City.__init__(self, *city_args, **kwargs)
        self.__id = id_neighborhood
        self.__name = name_neighborhood
        self.__number = number_block
```

Definition of the `Block`:

```
class Block(Neighborhood):
    def __init__(self, id_block, number_block, number_flats, *neighborhood_args, **kwargs):
        Neighborhood.__init__(*neighborhood_args, **kwargs)
        self.__id = id_block
        self.__number_b = number_block
        self.__number_f = number_flats
```

Then I declare entities:

```
city = City(5, "New York")
neighborhood = Neighborhood(1, "Brooklyn", 500, 5, "New York")
block = Block(11, 2, 20, 1, "Brooklyn", 500, 5, "New York")
```

And get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_City__id'
```

Comment: Why are you using inheritance for this? It seems more like a composition problem. Also what's with the `__two_leading_underscore` attributes? Do you mean to use name mangling?

Comment: Don't use double leading underscores in your variable names.  Ever.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: do use them when designing a framework and you need to minimise the chance developers using your framework will create attribute names that clash with your internal implementation. That's what the feature is designed for.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to pass `self` to `Neighborhood.__init__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right,  I should have qualified my statement.  But I think the advice will serve the OP well for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass in `self` in your `Block.__init__()` implementation:

```
Neighborhood.__init__(*neighborhood_args, **kwargs)
```

so the first argument passed in is an integer instead. Now `Neighbourhood.__init__()` has `self` bound to `1`, and you get your error. Simply add in `self`:

```
class Block(Neighborhood):
    def __init__(self, id_block, number_block, number_flats, *neighborhood_args, **kwargs):
        Neighborhood.__init__(self, *neighborhood_args, **kwargs)
```